# Batch rename files by rearranging the names

Tags: windows, scripting, file-rename

There are lots of questions asked about batch renaming already, but I think my problem is a bit different. I need to rename a lot of files by switching around the components of the filename.

Example:

**Original filename**:  BGP-2012-LOG-KTH-01.doc

**New filename**:       2012-BGP-KTH-LOG-01.doc

The different parts of the filename are delimited by dashes. Been ages since I ever had to script anything, I've never been good at it anyway. Hopefully someone can help. I'm on windows 7, so powershell, or vbscript may be the easiest (but then I'm no expert).

Comment: Is each token between the dashes always the same length?

Answer (score 0):

```
ls | %{ rename-item $_.name ($_.name -replace '^(\w+)-(\w+)-(\w+)-(\w+)', '$2-$1-$4-$3')}
```